# Passing bash variable into inline perl script

Tags: bash, perl, webserver, centos7

Reference the 2nd to last line in my script. For some reason Perl is not able to access the variable `$perlPort` how can I fix this? Note: `$perlPort` is a bash variable location before my perl script

```
perl -e '
{
    package MyWebServer;
    use HTTP::Server::Simple::CGI;
    use base qw(HTTP::Server::Simple::CGI);
    my %dispatch = (
        "/" => \&resp_hello,
    );


    sub handle_request {
        my $self = shift;
        my $cgi  = shift;
        my $path = $cgi->path_info();
        my $handler = $dispatch{$path};
        if (ref($handler) eq "CODE") {
            print "HTTP/1.0 200 OK\r\n";
            $handler->($cgi);
        } else {
            print "HTTP/1.0 404 Not found\r\n";
            print $cgi->header,
            $cgi->start_html("Not found"),
            $cgi->h1("Not found"),
            $cgi->end_html;
        }
    }


    sub resp_hello {
        my $cgi  = shift;   # CGI.pm object
        return if !ref $cgi;
        my $who = $cgi->param("name");   
        print $cgi->header,
            $cgi->start_html("Hello"),
            $cgi->h1("Hello Perl"),
            $cgi->end_html;
    }
}


my $pid = MyWebServer->new($perlPort)->background();
print "Use 'kill $pid' to stop server.\n";'
```

Comment: In the same way you wrote `'kill $pid'` why you don't write `'$perlPort'`?

Comment: `$perlPort` => `$ENV{perlPort}`

Answer (score 5):

```
export perlPort
perl -e '
...
my $pid = MyWebServer->new($ENV{perlPort})->background();
'
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `-s` switch to pass variables.  See http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html

```
perl -se '
...
my $pid = MyWebBrowser->new($perlPort)->background();
...' -- -perlPort="$perlPort"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can still pass command line arguments to your script. Replace `$perlPort` with `$ARGV[0]`, then call you script as

```
perl -e $' ...
         my $pid = MyWebServer->new($ARGV[0])->background();
         print "Use \'kill $pid\' to stop server.\n";' "$perlPort"
```

Note the other problem: You can't include single quotes inside a single-quoted string in `bash`. You can work around this by using a `$'...'`-quoted string as the argument to Perl, which *can* contain escaped single quotes. If your script doesn't need to read from standard input, it would be a better idea to have `perl` read from a here-document instead.

```
perl <<'EOF' "$perlPort"
{
package MyWebServer;
use HTTP::Server::Simple::CGI;
...
my $pid = MyWebServer->new($ARGV[0])->background();
print "Use 'kill $pid' to stop server.\n";
EOF
```

The *best* idea is to simply use a script file instead of trying to construct the script on the command line.

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -e '
   ...
my $pid = MyWebServer->new('$perlPort')->background();
   ...
```

Comment: Unquoted parameter expansions are subject to word-splitting and pathname expansion. The *intended* value (an integer) is safe, but this is fragile.